# How to add a Div to another div and pass the newly created div to Jquery printArea function

Tags: jquery, html

I want to print a div using Jquery printArea function.
But before printing I want to add a footer to the current div.

Can any one help me in this.

```
<div id="div1">
    <p> Hiiii </p>
    <p> Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <p> Footer</p>
</div>

<button type="button" id="bt1">print</button>
```

and my script is

```
$("#bt1").click(function(){
    var mode = 'iframe'; 
    var close = mode == "popup";
    var options = { mode : mode, popClose : close};
    var newcontent =  $("#div1");
    newcontent = newcontent.append("#div2");

    newcontent.printArea( options );
});
```

But its only printing div1 it's not appending div2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.html()` as follow

```
$("#div1").append($("#div2").html());
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms1tt3fg/).